# Concourse CI tool to continuously monitor an S3 bucket and trigger job if a file appears

Tags: amazon-s3, concourse, concourse-s3-resource

I need to be able to trigger a Concourse task when a file appears in an Amazon S3 bucket.

There is this Concourse tool:
https://github.com/pivotalservices/concourse-curl-resource

However I am looking to test for the existence of a file, and if it exists, trigger another job, then delete the file to reset.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The s3 resource can handle this with a [versioned file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html). Every time you update/change the same file, the resource will detect a new update, and then trigger a job.

Comment: The s3 resource can be set to watch for files that don't exist yet. You can point it at a nonexistent file and set it to trigger whenever a new version of that file is detected.